# Javascript function .xls to .csv

Tags: javascript, json

I am using IE 9. My js function works in both Chrome and IE, it's just that it doesn't save the file in right format in IE. I want to save as .csv, in IE javascript only gives me an option to save in .xls.
Following is the function I created:

```
downloadCSV: function(strData, strFileName){
            var strMimeType = "application/octet-stream";

            if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE10
                return navigator.msSaveBlob(new Blob([strData], {type: strMimeType}), strFileName+".csv");
            }

            var a = Construct.create("a",{}, document.body);
            if ('download' in a) { //html5 A[download] FF and Chrome
                a.href = "data:" + strMimeType + "," + encodeURIComponent(strData);
                a.setAttribute("download", strFileName+".csv");
                a.innerHTML = "downloading...";
                setTimeout(function() {
                    a.click();
                    Construct.destroy(a);
                }, 66);
                return true;
            }

            var f = Construct.create("iframe",{}, document.body);
            if (typeof (window.ActiveXObject) == "undefined") {//old Chrome + FF
                f.src = "data:" + strMimeType + "," + encodeURIComponent(strData);
            } else {// IE 9
                var doc = f.contentWindow.document;
                doc.open("text/html");
                doc.charset = "utf-8";
                doc.write(strData);
                doc.close();
                doc.execCommand("SaveAs", null, strFileName+".csv");
            }
            setTimeout(function() {
                Construct.destroy(f);
            }, 333);
            return true;
        }
```

P.S. JavaScript is enabled in IE9

Comment: Have you tried using the `text/csv` MIME?

Comment: Why would it be saved as `.xls`? Do you mean it tries to open the csv file with Excel and then save from there?

Comment: It converts data into csv format and downloads the file

Comment: text/csv MIME doesn't work